# Qt running button

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to make a program where a button has to run away from the mouse. It works fine, but sometimes the button just stops moving. What's wrong?

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "joke.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTime time(0, 0, 0);
    qsrand(time.secsTo(QTime::currentTime()));
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Joke joke;
    joke.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

joke.h

```
#ifndef JOKE_H
#define JOKE_H
#include <QtGui>

class Joke: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QLabel *label;
    QPushButton *button;

protected:
    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *);


public:
    Joke(QWidget *pwgt = 0);

public slots:
    void buttonClicked();
};

#endif // JOKE_H
```

joke.cpp

```
#include "joke.h"

bool isClicked = false;

Joke::Joke(QWidget *pwgt): QWidget(pwgt)
{
    QPalette *pal = new QPalette;
    QPixmap pix("background.jpg");
    QDesktopWidget *desktop = new QDesktopWidget;
    QRect size = desktop->availableGeometry(desktop->primaryScreen());

    int deskHeight = desktop->geometry().height();
    int deskWidth = size.width();

    pal->setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(pix));

    button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setText("Click Me");
    button->resize(75, 25);
    button->move((deskWidth / 2), (deskHeight / 2));
    button->installEventFilter(this);

    label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText("<FONT color=red size=30><B>Sup! Try to CLICK the BUTTON!</B></FONT>");
    label->resize(deskWidth, 100);
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));

    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    this->setPalette(*pal);
    this->showMaximized();
}

void Joke::buttonClicked()
{
    label->setText("<FONT color=green size=30<B>Congratz! You've done it!</B></FONT>");
    button->setText("Exit");
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    isClicked = true;
}

bool Joke::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
{
    if(isClicked == true)
    {
        button->move(0, 0);
    }
    if(obj == button)
    {
        if(ev->type() == QEvent::Enter)
        {
            int x = qrand() % 1900;
            int y = qrand() % 1000;
            button->move(x, y);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: When does the button stop? When you hit the window border?

Comment: It stops when i'm trying to press it. If mouse follows the button without pressing LMB, the bug is out

Comment: Got the problem. Sometimes button had coordinates that label has. Anyway thanks for reply.

Comment: no problem, have fun with your jokey button ;)